# SvelteKit: Javascript file in <svelte:head> is only read on first page load - it is present in the browser but not read after page reload

Tags: sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit app that is not reading a Javascript file. The app references a CSS file and a Javascript file in the static ("public") folder, from a layout file. The files are referenced in a `<svelte:head>` tag in the layout file as follows:

```html
<svelte:head>
    <script src="/js/script.js" on:load={() => console.log('script:initialize')}></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
</svelte:head>
```

The CSS file is working as expected.  The Javascript file referenced by the script tag works on initial page load, but not after a page refresh. The server must be restarted for the js file to be read. The js file is present in the browser (the code can be viewed using the browser's dev tools), but the code only works if there's no page reload, and likewise the console.log above only works on initial page load, not on reload.

Versions of SvelteKit are from 1.0.0-next.345 to 1.0.0-next.420.

The file does not work when placed in app.html.

It starts with

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { ...
```

If I add a js file to the static folder with the content `console.log('hello')` and add `<script src="/js/hello.js" on:load={() => console.log('script:initialize:hello')}></script>` to the `<svelte:head>` tag, the browser logs `"hello"`, and not `"script:initialize:hello"`.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place? Ideally you should just `import` from the `<script>` of the component.

Comment: Thanks, the file is not a module, and when converted to a module with ```export```,  the code still does not work - it only works on first page load when referenced in the svelte:head tag.

Comment: The the problem is probably the script itself

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm leaning towards that not being the case, since it works fine in an HTML, JS, CSS app without SvelteKit, and it works fine in SvelteKit on initial page load, but not after any refresh.

Comment: Something not working after a refresh is a horrible sign, that simply should not happen...

Comment: Hi, I'm currently having this issue with importing an external library. Did you find a solution to this? Thanks